# Blank lines not allowed in multi-line string when using the Yaml component of symfony?

Tags: symfony, yaml

```
<?php

  $raw = <<<YAML
foo:
  bar:
  - field1: value
    field2: |
      bla

      bla
      bla
YAML;


\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse($raw);
?>
```

This code results in a `ParseException` (Using symfony yaml component 2.8.14)

> Unable to parse at line 7 (near "    bla").

According to [this](http://www.yamllint.com/), the syntax is correct. Does anybody know if this is a bug in the Yaml parser of symfony? Could not find anything about it in their docs.

Comment: What happens if you keep the indentation (spaces at the beginning) on the empty line? Still an error?

Comment: @Xymanek Yes, there's still an error.

Comment: No clue then, sorry

Comment: For anyone else tracking this issue, please see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21005

Comment: The issue has been fixed by the symfony developers. See [github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21084](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/21084)